# SQL -- Displaying Results as Percentages

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select retention
 , Sum(count(retention)) over(order by retention desc) as Num_Users_Retained
  from (select player_id
         , round(init_dtime-create_dtime,0) as retention
      from player
     where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
       and init_dtime is not null)
  Group by retention
  order by retention
```

This query displays two columns: The first column being the day of this year(day 0 is jan-1,day 259 is today sep-16) and the second column being the retention. Day 0 has 428,000 because all users are retained, Day 1 has 300K (since 128K people didnt log in after their first day), and the number keeps decreasing as time goes on. I want to show another column for the percentages that each day is of day 0. Is that clear enough or should I provide further detail?

Comment: are you sure the query listed is your actual query?

Comment: @FlorinGhita yes it is exactly the query, i just ran it again to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select retention
     , Num_Users_Retained
     , round(Num_Users_Retained/max(Num_Users_Retained) over() * 100, 2) as perc
  from (select retention
             , Sum(count(retention)) over(order by retention desc) as Num_Users_Retained
         from (select player_id
                    , round(init_dtime-create_dtime,0) as retention
                from player
               where Trunc(Create_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-jan-01','yyyy-mon-dd')
                 and init_dtime is not null
              )
        Group by retention
        order by retention)
 order by retention
```